# JPanel Settings

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have 2 java files, here is my main class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Chess");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        UserInterface ui = new UserInterface();
        f.add(ui);
        f.setSize(600, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Here is my UserInterface class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class UserInterface extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponet(Graphics g){

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        System.out.println("This was called");
        g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
        g.setColor(new Color(190, 81, 215));
        g.fillRect(40, 20, 80, 50);
    }

}
```

Now, for some reason, my `paintComponet()` function is never called. My print statement is never outputted. Does anyone know why? I feel like I have made a very simple mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Add `@Override` to you method

```
@Override
public void paintComponet(Graphics g){
```

Now, fix the compiler error. While you're doing that, add a `super.paintComponent(g)` before you perform any custom painting, this will prevent lots of nasty paint artefacts from occurring

When overriding methods, it's important to use the `@Override` annotation as it allows the compiler to tell you when you've made a mistake